# How to apply Style and effect on ink filepicker through Javascript

Tags: filepicker.io

I am stucked on **filepicker.io** API from long days that how do i add **style/css** through javascript in ink filepicker.
I have also idea about i can add style to my **ink filepicker** from my account also but i have two **filepicker.io** on my same page i just want to change style for only one dialog so is there any way to do it.

```
        filepicker.pick({ mimetype: "image/*" }, function (InkBlob) {     
                                        json = InkBlob;    
                                        var InkbolobFilename = json.filename; 
                                        var InkbolobUrl = json.url; 
                                    });
```

This my code snap so please help me out where i can add my css url.

Comment: Filepicker API has not css parameter. The only way you can set custom css file is by Filepicker Dev portal. Custom css is linked to specific application. If you want to have two different style for dialog you have to use second app.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind suport.
but is it possible to impliment two filepickers with diffrent App keys in one page?

Comment: Sure, just set another key just before filepicker.pick()